# How to get selected month last date last timestamp in java?

Tags: java

From the below java code I'm getting a month First & last dateTimestamp, but here i need last dateTimestamp as - "Mon Aug 31 23:59:59 IST 2015" instead of - "Mon Aug 31 00:00:00 IST 2015"?

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = 2015;
        int month = 07;
        cal.set(cal.DATE,1);
        cal.set(cal.YEAR,year);
        cal.set(cal.MONTH, month);
        String firstDate = (cal.getActualMinimum(cal.DATE) + "/" + (month+1) + "/" +year);
        System.out.println("firstDate-->"+"\t"+firstDate);
        String lastDate = (cal.getActualMaximum(cal.DATE) + "/" + (month+1) + "/" +year);
        System.out.println("lastDate-->"+"\t"+lastDate);
        DateFormat firstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date beginDate = firstFormat.parse(firstDate);
        System.out.println("BeginDate Timestamp"+ "\t" + beginDate);
        DateFormat secoundFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date endDate = secoundFormat.parse(lastDate);
        System.out.println("endDate Timestamp"+ "\t" + endDate);
```

Output:->

```
firstDate-->    1/8/2015
lastDate-->    31/8/2015
BeginDate Timestamp Sat Aug 01 00:00:00 IST 2015
endDate Timestamp   Mon Aug 31 00:00:00 IST 2015
```

Please help me if we have any solution.

Comment: You could add one day, and subtract one second. Or you could set the hour, minute, second and millisecond to whatever value you like. Couldn't you?

Comment: With `cal.set(...)` just like you do in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I got a solution for my question!!!
I think it will help u too...

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year=2015;
        int month=7;
        int date=31;
        int hourOfDay=23;
        int minute=59;
        int second=59;
        int milliSecond=999;
        calendar.set(year, month, date, hourOfDay, minute, second);
        calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, milliSecond);
        System.out.println("Time from Calendar: "+calendar.getTime());
        long timeInMilliSeconds=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("timeInMilliSeconds from calendar: "+timeInMilliSeconds);
        Timestamp timestamp=new Timestamp(timeInMilliSeconds);
        System.out.println(timestamp);
```

The above program gives the last date last timestamp in a selected month.
getTimeInMillis() takes the time from Jan 01, 1970 to current time in Milliseconds.
Using those milliseconds i'm getting the Timestamp.
Thank you for your help guys!!!

OutPut:->

```
Time from Calendar: Mon Aug 31 23:59:59 IST 2015
timeInMilliSeconds from calendar: 1441045799999
2015-08-31 23:59:59.999
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, it looks as if you want to pass a year and month into a method, and get back the last day of the passed month.

I would suggest consider (in this order):

1. which jdk you use
2. configuration of calendar
3. configuration of timezone (maybe)
4. using jodatime

As of 1.8 many JodaTime-like features have been added to the jdk- e.g. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html (If you arent using 1.8 you can use the joda lib, assuming your organization allows it)

Calendar.getInstance() gives a default TimeZone and a default Locale, which means the *definitions of the running JVM*. You may or may not need to consider this and implement more than just getInstance(). See API javadoc.

Assuming a Gregeorian Calendar (hey, you could be Bahaian and have 19 months in the year ...) , here is one **partial** implementation using JDK 1.7, JodaTime jar 2.2, validation-1.0.0.GA jar:

```
@Test
public void testDate() {

    final String dateStringOfFirstDay = "1.7.2015";
    final Date lastDayOfMonth = getLastDayOfMonth(dateStringOfFirstDay);
    Assert.assertNotNull(lastDayOfMonth);
    //more assertions ...
}

private Date getLastDayOfMonth(@NotNull String dateStringOfFirstDay) {

    //further validation here necessary according to required date format 
    DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(dateStringOfFirstDay);
    return dt.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue().toDate();
}
```

The defintion of DateFormat/DateTimeFormat and further result assertions is left up to you.

Best of luck!